# What's the difference between www & public_html folder?

Tags: linux, shared-hosting

What's the difference between the www & public_html folder on the same server on my shared linux hosting. I've seen data is same on both of these folders. Is one of them just a redirect or is the data getting replicated. What is the purpose of 2 folders or even a redirect folder?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It depends entirely on the local configuration; ask your hosting provider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary difference would be a preference between naming conventions and how your hosting service configured it.  I have typically used `public_html` for user directories and often `www` for system-wide but that's more a personal convention.

In all likelihood, there is no difference but we can't speak for an arbitrary configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the www folder is simply a symbolic link of public_html.

Comment: A mirror?  What, using more disk-space?  That seems highly unlikely.

Comment: I think he means symbolic link.

Comment: My mistake, typing quickly without thinking. Everyone makes mistakes. More like "mirrors" - ie same content, not literally.