# Where should the web server root directory go in linux?

Tags: web-server

I see that Apache and Nginx both use var/www as their web root - but that directory is not covered in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html). I also see some servers with the web root in the `/home/username/www` directory. So where does the web root go? Or rather, *where should it go most of the time for the common web server?*

Comment: I've answered two similar questions.  See: http://serverfault.com/questions/127472/whats-the-difference-between-www-public-html-folder/127474#127474 and http://serverfault.com/questions/135711/what-is-the-proper-way-to-set-up-the-apache-document-root-in-terms-of-privileges/135717#135717

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many SysAdmins use non-standard paths in order to avoid an easy-to-guess path in case of attacks.

If you are building an Internet web server I suggest considering a non-standard path.

Comment: hmmm.. good point. I wonder how much help that would actually be in an attack. Kind of like switching the SSH port from 22. Should I create a root level nonstandard path like `/www-data` or just add to an existing path like `/srv/www-data/`?

Comment: Putting SSH on a different port does not save you from a nmap portscan: in a few minutes nmap can guess the ssh port.

Using non-standard path such as /MyData/WebSites/sitename01, /MyData/WebSites/sitename02 and so on can save you from various kind of vulnerability attacks that try to run or read some files using a relative path. If you take a look at a apache logfile, you can see some attacks using relative paths such as ../../../etc/passwd. That said, there is no silver bullet in security.

Comment: This is just security by obscurity. If somebody has enough access to your server to be able to read, or worse, _modify_ arbitrary files on your server, the web root is the thing you should worry _least_ about.

Answer (score 21):

Distros use `/var/www` because it is for *"transient and temporary files"*.  The files installed there are just for checking if the server is working.  After that, you can safely delete the folder.

But `/var/www` is not where you are *supposed* to install your own web source files.  There is an argument to be made for using `/usr/local/<app>` if the web site files are static, but the most appropriate place is in `/srv/<app>` or `/srv/www/<app>`.  Notably, your OS should never write to `/usr/local` or `/srv`, so they are both safe places for your own shared files.  But `/srv` is for *"data for services provided by this system"*, which is exactly what web source code is.

Comment: Now that you've bumped a six year old, _answered_, question... you might as well put in the effort to link to some references to back your posit -- LFH, `man hier`, etc.

Comment: I could, but the reference I would link to is already in the original question, so that seems silly.

Comment: what's "srv"? there's no such a folder.

Comment: As described above and in the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard link, `/srv` is the standard directory on Unix-like systems for storing files used by system services.  If you don't have a directory called `/srv`. you can create one, but your system may have some other, OS-specific place for this.  `/srv` is present on RedHat and Debian based systems, which is like 99% of Linuxes.

Answer (score 2):

by default most of Linux Flavors use

```
var/www/html
```